# Angular 2 - date.getMonth is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

I'm using this [Angular-2-datepicker](https://github.com/koleary94/Angular-2-Datepicker). Everything works, however everytime I try to set the [(date)] attribute, it gives me the error.

> date.getMonth is not a function

I've looked up some info and found out it could be because my variable is not of type date, however mine is, so I'm right now I'm stuck and cant find a solution.

**My HTML:**

```
...
<material-datepicker dateFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" weekStart="1" [(date)]="definitionDetails.From"></material-datepicker>
...
```

**My Model:**

```
export class ClosingDayDefinition implements Serializable<ClosingDayDefinition> {

    ID: number;
    DescriptionID: number;
    Info: models.DefinitionDetailInfo;
    Description: models.DefinitionDescription;
    CodeId: number;
    From: Date;
    To: Date;
    Recurring: boolean;
    Holiday: boolean;
    Groups: Array<models.ClosingDayGroup>;
    TypeName: string;
```

**My Component:**

```
...
public definitionDetails: models.ClosingDayDefinition;
...
```

**Var Log:**

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like the `From` property contains a string, and not a `Date` object.

I'm guessing you're getting this date string from an API of some sort, try parsing it as a date instead of storing it straight away:

This will work

```
new Date('2017-03-08T00:00:00+01:00')
```

Comment: I'm very new to angular 2 but isn't that what the class is for? Since I create a new instance of `class ClosingDayDefinition` wouldn't it give me errors if it wasn't of type date?

Comment: That's what TypeScript is for, but it can only check types before compilation, if the actual data is received at runtime, it will never know, you have to make sure you're expecting the same type you defined in your class, and if it's not the same type, transform it accordingly.

Comment: Yes! that was the problem, I recceived a string. I now transformed it to a date and it solved the issue. Thanks!